# Error LPT2.280C1DID.cer when expanding IIS hosting tree

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7.5

When trying to expand the web hosting as one week ago, now its not working anymore. I found not a lot related answers.

I have tried `sfc /scannow`and restart and scandisk. All without success.

Perhaps it occured when harddisk was full for short time. Now over 50Gb are free.

[image]

Comment: Disk full is a very critical condition that many in-memory states were not properly written to disk and lost during server reboot forever. If I were you I would try to restore from a previous backup, not to continue on an unstable machine. There isn't a reliable way to manually fix everything back to normal.

Comment: I absolute agree with you. What I am not know about is the file LPT2.280C1DID.cer and its function depending the system, so I guess it can be also something else than your and my explained issue of full disk.